# Psql lookbehind regex for multiple value replacement

Tags: regex, psql

I am looking to find three values and replace them with regex without knowing exactly what is behind other than a rough idea. For example

`word [1,2,3]`

`232 word[1 , 2, 3]`

`1d1 word   [1,2, 3]`

In both cases I'm exclusively looking to match and replace 1, 2 and 3.

As I understand it, lookbehind doesn't support unknown lengths.

Is there an elegant way of doing this?

It would also be good to know how to do this outwith Sql where conditionals aren't an option

Thanks.

Edit:

I figure I can use `WHERE match_string ~ 'word'` to an extent.

Comment: If your regex engine supports [positive lookbehinds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) then maybe [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/7tdTIB/1/) `(?<=\[)(\d)\s?,\s?(\d),\s?(\d)(?=\])` might help you

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html

Comment: conditionals are available if you put the logic into a function.    I'm not clear why you need either conditionals or look behind.

Comment: @CalvinTaylor. I know there will always be a standard string with a bit of fuzzy formatting with white space characters. Since psql doesn't support nested returns I can't match the values directly and reference them as necessary. In the end I used  an inverse approach to REGEXP_REPLACE to alienate the values. It's not perfect as it currently matches n results rather than three but it does the job for now. I like your RETURN NEXT idea, if you post it as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write a function to process however you like.  Checkout [postres control structures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html)

You can return one processed row at a time or make a function to process your field? to return the proper text.  eg select myfix(poordatafield) from sometable;

There are performance considerations for using return next.